# No matching distribution found for <package>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, quick-install-package

`pip install InvoiceGenerator` or `pip3 install InvoiceGenerator`

returns:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/c4/3b9b764a1cdbf1dd3d0c2c775c5278f912daf710d7d6fac612c0d88d5f77/InvoiceGenerator-0.1.1.tar.gz#sha256
=ee742449f4b93c44064657456fa00c33637e6ebebb9533256182090638543ad8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/invoicegenerator/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python
setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

  Downloading InvoiceGenerator-0.1.0.tar.gz (3.7 kB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shoaib\django\virtual_venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]
= '"'"'C:\\Users\\shoaib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_bye42ck\\invoicegenerator_822aa65c03614f379e279162c2c5770a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shoaib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_bye42ck\\invoicegenerator_822aa65c03614f379e279162c2c5770a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fi
le__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close()
;exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\shoaib\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fs69yz3y'
         cwd: C:\Users\shoaib\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bye42ck\invoicegenerator_822aa65c03614f379e279162c2c5770a\

    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\shoaib\django\virtual_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension
      File "c:\users\shoaib\django\virtual_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "c:\users\shoaib\django\virtual_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\shoaib\django\virtual_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/67/b4d511793065ff7519fb5e90597f6fa46dd02e7698e2355f4f5cf5360502/InvoiceGenerator-0.1.0.tar.gz#sha256
=81692a84f45ba000ba472b9cd6c9e55070b20cf5b595fda23f3e3f5223cde067 (from https://pypi.org/simple/invoicegenerator/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python
setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement InvoiceGenerator (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.
7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 1.0.1, 1.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for InvoiceGenerator
```

I can't understand why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: what version python are you running

Comment: version - Python 3.8.6

Comment: The error looks like you have a configuration file pointing to a different repository than the standard PyPI. Can you please reveal the full error message and any pertinent `.piprc` or similar?

Comment: Try pip install yahoofinancials==1.6

Comment: Don't post updates as answers; answers should only contain posts which actually attempt to solve the problem at the top of hhis page. Please instead [edit] your question if you want to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this steps to solve this error, it's worked in my case

- `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`
- check python module name on PyPI and install that module (e.g, pip3 install socketIO)
- rerun this command `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`